# Chrome ask for track-by but not Firefox

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I'm working on vueJs in Symfony project. I have a vue that worked great until few days. I didn't change anything that have something to do with that vue but with no reason since few days, it doesn't work on chrome (which I use since the beginning) but works great on Firefox.

So what I do is a select:

```
<select v-model="selectedStock">
      <option :value="stock.id"v-for="stock in stocks">{{ stock.name }}</option>
</select>
```

my "stocks" are init with that:

```
loadStocks () {
    this.$http({
        url: 'api/stocks',
        method: 'get'
    }).then( response => {
        this.stocks = response.data
    })
},
```

and my function called by the route `api/stocks` is:

```
 public function indexAction ()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $stocks = $em->getRepository('RBOrdersBundle:Stock')->findAll();

    return new JsonResponse($this->get('rb.serializer')->onEntity($stocks)->toArray());
}
```

and when I'm going on `local/api/stocks` I have an array with 2 object

and when in `loadStocks()` in the response part I do : `alert(typeof response.data)` chrome give me string and Firefox gives me Object

And finally the console in Chrome shows me:

> main.js:39752 [Vue warn]: Duplicate value found in v-for="stock in stocks": "0". Use track-by="$index" if you are expecting duplicate values. (found in component: `<reassort-tool>`)

but like 20 times with a bunch of different letter and I'm pretty sure there is no duplicate in my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the problem. Since a recent update from chrome you need to upgrade vue-ressource. So I changed my `package.json` from

```
"vue-resource": "^0.9.3",
```

to

```
"vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
```

a little npm updat and good to go.